# Python MySQL Connector: caching_sha2_password plugin

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to MySQL (8.0.11) from Python (3.6) on Windows 7 with the following code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='*****',
                                database='test')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
```

However i get following error message:

> Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: ` pip install --user mysql-connector-python`

Comment: The comment by @hassanzadeh.sd should be the accepted answer. Maybe modifying thee authentication method on the server to an older encryption scheme works, but a) downgrading encryption for expedience is a bad idea and b) sometimes you don't have control over the server (I was connecting to a vendor-managed DB) and can't.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this to your connection argument: `auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'`, this will force the connection to use the native plugin instead of the SHA2 plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and answers in this thread doesn't work for me. In case you want to solve in my way, download Older version of MySQL and you can avoid this error.

For Mac and Windows [Link](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

Comment: I am having `mysql-connector-python==8.0.21` and `mysql==8.0.21` ye the `caching_sha2_password` error is occurring in `python==3.8.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python **connector** does not support the authentication plugin '*caching_sha2_password*' and you need to update it.
Be sure to download the correct connector based on your operating system, MySQL version and the Python version you use from the official [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) site.

Answer (score -1):

for mysql-connector, you should find one which work well among below 3 packages

mysql-connector
mysql-connector-python
mysql-connector-python-rf

Answer (score -1):

Try execute your python code with python3. That worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32294385)